# Angular - Open a view in a modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal, sweetalert

I built my login page as a view using angularjs which is perfectly working, now I want to open the same screen but using a modal. In order to open that modal from any page without being redirected to another screen. Is that possible? Can I reuse the code in that view/controller? Or I should create a different screen?
If I need to create a new screen for the modal, could you point me to the right direction for that?

Comment: I would change the 'login page' and make it as a directive and place the directive within the modal html. Most of your existing code should be able to be reused. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bootstrap [modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) with your view and controller:

```
myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope, $uibModal) {
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
      });
  };
});
```

to make it look nicer you can use a wrapping template and include the `login.html` into it:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal login!</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" ng-include="'login.html'"></div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    I'm a footer
</div>
```

To use bootstrap modal - you have to include the following into the `index.html`:

```
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and have a dependency for your module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Then you'll have it injected by name `$uibModal`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have one issue when trying to do this. I get Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal. I searched it but I only found that that is because i don't have 'ui.bootstrap', in the module definition, but it is there... So I don't know which can be the issue here

Comment: I realized I have to use modal instead of uibModal